# Missing file with geocaching API example PHP

Tags: php, api, cakephp, geocaching

I've been trying to replicate [this](https://github.com/Surfoo/geocaching-api) Geocaching API example by Surfoo. I dropped the files on my server and now I'm getting:

```
Warning: require(/geocaching/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /geocaching/index.php on line 6
```

This file isn't anywhere to be seen with the downloaded example and I haven't heard anything back from the owner yet. So is this simply a missing file or is this a file I need to build myself to load the appropriate code? I know CakePHP uses vendors and the like but I have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: My guess is that the example expects a 'psr-0' autoloader to be present (https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md). However, I wonder if that example will play nice together with CakePHP. CakePHP 2.x currently doesn't play nice with namespaces, so you may be running in a lot of other problems as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer to this question.

Basically I needed [PHP composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to manage dependencies. for anyone interested just follow the getting started section to install the relevant files.

For anyone who is interested in using the [Geocaching API](http://www.geocaching.com/live/apidevelopers/) with PHP I have put together a [Git Repository](https://github.com/jampez77/geocaching-api) which should work right out of the box. Just drop all file on your server.